# When/where/how did weekly "kiddush" become the norm?

Tags: shabbat, history, food, synagogue, kiddush

At the typical American synagogue -- and most in Europe as well, at this point I think -- it's expected that after the Shabbos morning prayers, there will be "kiddush", but people don't sit down to bread and have a full meal, they just walk around and have crackers, cake, or the like.

When did that become the norm? I don't *think* it was a thing in pre-WWII Europe nor the Middle East? (If so please correct me?) Is this another one where American synagogues essentially picked up what was popular in other American houses of worship?

Comment: There's a long tradition of eating something dairy before mussaf coming from Yekkeland. (Though we tend to sit down when we eat.)

Comment: @Kazibácsi How long?

Comment: @DoubleAA IIRC correctly it is at least attested since the 17th-18th century, but I have to look up sources (that I don't have now at hand).

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kiddush_club#:~:text=There%20is%20evidence,meal.%5B5%5D), the Kiddush Club concept goes back at least to the 16th century.

Comment: The answer at [Where did the idea of a shul kiddush come from](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/87858/where-did-the-idea-of-a-shul-kiddush-come-from) is less than entirely satisfactory, but I think this is close enough that it's a dupe